# Swift : alamofire post with json body

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm using alarmofire to implement POST request.

The goal is to post as :

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
     --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"dest":"Place","reason":"Reason","carId":1,"starttime":1496975475840,"departmentId":3,"distance":0.0,"driverId":1}' 
     'http://localhost:8080/serviceCar/v1_0/placeOrder?access_token=25621648-1da5-438e-a52c-f927e2c59de4'
```

The URL is `http://localhost:8080/serviceCar/v1_0/placeOrder`

And I have an order class, how can I post the object as request body and also send token as form data?

Comment: Show us your Alamofire request code.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#custom-encoding) is writen this case which you want.

*In the event that the provided ParameterEncoding types do not meet your needs, you can create your own custom encoding. Here's a quick example of how you could build a custom JSONStringArrayEncoding type to encode a JSON string array onto a Request.*

```
struct JSONStringArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    private let array: [String]

    init(array: [String]) {
        self.array = array
    }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()

        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: [])

        if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest.httpBody = data

        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

This is example of setting header of request[[from doc]](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-basic-authentication):

```
let user = "user"
let password = "password"

var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]

if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
    headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
}

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/password", headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```